# Angular - Use routes parameter in route setup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-routing

I'm trying to create a BaseController which my controllers can extend to handle the history action for all models. Currently (for the other routes), I set it up like so:

```js
$routeProvider.when('/', {
  redirectTo: '/static/campaigns'
}).when('/static/campaigns/new', {
  templateUrl: 'campaigns/new.html',
  controller: 'CampaignNewController'
}).....
```

What I want to do for the history routes would be a general route which would cover all models, but I'm not sure if there's a way to use the route parameters within the setup like below.

```js
when('/static/history/:model_name', {
  templateUrl: model_name + '/history.html',
  controller: model_name + 'Controller'
})
```

Comment: Best way to know, is to try :)

Comment: @IsraGab I did although it throws a ReferenceError saying `model_name` isn't defined

Answer (score 0):

If you look at documentation : 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#when
you may notice that, templateurl can be a string or a function. Perhaps if you created a function on the right hand side of templateUrl and injected $routeParams and read the value of model_name and returned a string with model_name, it might just work.

You wont be able to do the same for controller;  however, you will have to create a service, that takes model_name as input and does the same logic as multiple controllers would.